# Python - iterate over two lists and find matches and position of mis-matches

Tags: python-2.7, list

I am working in Python 2.7

I am trying to iterate over 2 lists, of un-equal length, and I want to create a new list, containing the matching elements (same elements in the same position), and when the elements do not match, I need to have some text as well as the position of the miss-matching elements.

```
list1=[1,2,3,4]
list2=[1,2,3,5,6]
```

This outputs the matches

```
match=[[b] for a, b in zip(list1, list2) if a==b]
```

result:

```
[1,2,3]
```

But I do not know, *in a one-liner*, how to also flag the mis-matches:

```
[1,2,3,"nomatch-pos4"]
```

or

```
[1,2,3,"nomatch-pos4","nomatch-pos5"]
```

It does not matter if it will iterate over the maximum or minimum of the 2 list lengths.

Comment: Move the conditional, so you're mapping rather than filtering: `[a if b else c for ...]`.

Comment: Don't do it in one line! If you're not trying to golf, use more lines if you need to, making it shorter won't make it more understandable or easy, just like it's happening to you!

Comment: What's supposed to happen if `list1 = [1, 2, 5]` btw? And is order guaranteed... What properties/constraints do you have?

Comment: @JonClements if `list1 = [1, 2, 5]` it should only find the first two elements as matches

Comment: @jonrsharpe: your suggestion did it, as elegant as possbile

Answer (score 1):

it first find the minimum of the two lists and iterate over the shorter list and check if an element in the list matches with other list in same position. check below code:

```
match = [list1[i] if list1[i] == list2[i] else 'nomatch-pos'+str(i+1) for i in range(0,min(len(list1),len(list2)))]
```